# how can make full screen app without AppBarLayout in android studio

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-tabs, android-appbarlayout, xml-layout

how can delete this blue and green section!?  do some different ways but not work! 
[image]

mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("News"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Archive"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Shop"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Beat Store"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

XML layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:background="#71ff76"
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

App Bar Layout is green but when i delete that my tabs gone! and that blue section seems not any where but always there :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend class with AppCompatActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Other initializations
  }
}
```

Declare different theme for this Activity in Manifest File

```
  <activity
     android:name=".MainActivity"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.FullScreenTheme">
     ...
```

Now in styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme.FullScreenTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
 </style>
```

If your layout is having any `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` component, remove that also

remove `android:background="#71ff76"` from `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` and  remove the mentioned padding `android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"`

Comment: blue section gone but that green section from app bar layout still has there

Comment: Update your current screen shot also below the last line in question. I have updated answer